# How to use JSON filter plugin to seperate message in JSON in logstash?

Tags: json, filter, logstash, kibana

This is my  logstash conf file.

```
input { 
http_poller{
    urls =>{
        urlname =>"http://ivivaanywhere.ivivacloud.com/api/Asset/Asset/All?apikey=SC:demo:64a9aa122143a5db&max=10&last=0"
    }
    request_timeout =>60
    schedule => {every => "20s"}
    codec => "line"
}
} 

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
   }


output { 
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
     index => "apilogs1"

 } 
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

I need to separate "message" in JSON in to fields to show in kibana

JSON message is some thing like this

```
[{"AssetID":"12341234","AssetCategoryKey":"50","Description":"Test AC Asset","OperationalStatus":"Operational","OperationalStatusChangeComment":"","InstalledLocationKey":"5","Make":"","Model":"","SerialNumber":"","BarCode":"","InstalledDate":"","CommissionedDate":"","Ownership":"","IsMobile":"0","ParentAssetKey":"","PurchasedDate":"","CurrentAmount":"","CurrentDepreciationAmount":"","UpdatedTime":"","PurchasedAmount":"","SalvageValue":"","DisposalDate":"","WarrantyExpiry":"","WarrantyStatus":"0","ClassKey":"","Specification":"","OwnerKey":"0","OwnerType":"","AssigneeAddedDate":"","AssigneeKey":"","AssigneeType":"","IsSold":"0","IsBackup":"0","CurrentLocationKey":"","Manufacturer_VendorKey":"","Supplier_VendorKey":"","EndofUsefullLifeDate":"","Hidden":"0","CreatedDateTime":"20200430:124909","CreatedUserKey":"141","ModifiedDateTime":"","ModifiedUserKey":"","IsLocked":"0","LockedUserKey":"","LockedDateTime":"","AssetKey":"389","ObjectKey":"389","__key__":"389","ObjectID":"12341234","InstalledLocationName":"Singapore.Office","AssetCategoryID":"Access
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify input codec as "json".

```
input { 
http_poller{
    urls =>{
        urlname =>"http://ivivaanywhere.ivivacloud.com/api/Asset/Asset/All?apikey=SC:demo:64a9aa122143a5db&max=10&last=0"
    }
    request_timeout =>60
    schedule => {every => "20s"}
    codec => "json"
}
}
```